# How to pass a variable from one function to an Sqlite3 query in another function in Python/Kivy

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I am currently building an app using Python 2.7, Kivy and Sqlite3.  I am having trouble passing a variable which is a value from a text_input widget(Date Picker from Kivy garden) this value is in a function `choose_date_water` and i am passing it to another function `view_water_figures` so that it can be used in querying an Sqlite table.  I have been trying for days to figure it out but without much luck and was hoping for a little help.

1. how do I pass the variable from the first function to the second?
2. Am I querying the Sqlite Table correctly using this variable `dp1`?

The relevant code:

```
class LogSheet(TabbedPanel):


    def choose_date_water(self):
        box = FloatLayout()
        box.add_widget(Label(text = "Select Date To View", font_size = (30), pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.9 }))
        #box.add_widget(TextInput(hint_text = "dd/mm/yyyy", font_size = (33), size_hint = (None, None), size = (300, 50),  pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.6 }))
        dp1 = box.add_widget(DatePicker(pHint_x = (0.35), pHint_y = (0.55), size_hint = (None, None), size = (190, 50), font_size = (33), pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.6 }))

        btn1 = Button(text = "OK", size_hint = (None, None), size = (200, 50), pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.25 })

        box.add_widget(btn1)

        popup1 = Popup(title = "Choose Date", title_size = (40), title_align = 'center', content = box, size_hint = (None, None), size = (600, 300))

        btn1.bind(on_press = self.view_water_figures, on_release = popup1.dismiss)

        popup1.open()
        return dp1

    def view_water_figures(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('logsheet.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        conn.execute("SELECT today_total_dw_vol, today_total_fw_vol, total_evap_out FROM waterfigures WHERE date = ?", (dp1,))
        conn.commit()
        wf = c.fetchall()

        for item in wf:
            I1 = str(item[1])
            I2 = str(item[2])
            I3 = str(item[3])   

        box = FloatLayout()
        box.add_widget(Label(text = "Total Dist Water Used:  " + I1, pos_hint={'center_x':0.15, 'center_y': 0.9 }))
        box.add_widget(Label(text = "Total Fresh Water Used: " + I2, pos_hint={'center_x':0.15, 'center_y': 0.8 }))
        box.add_widget(Label(text = "Total #1 Evap Produced: " + I3, pos_hint={'center_x':0.15, 'center_y': 0.7 }))



        btn1 = Button(text = "OK", size_hint = (None, None), size = (200, 50), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.25, 'center_y': .1})
        btn2 = Button(text = "Export Data To Excel", size_hint = (None, None), size = (200, 50), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.75, 'center_y': .1})

        box.add_widget(btn1)
        box.add_widget(btn2)

        popup2 = Popup(title='WATER FIGURES', title_size= (30), title_align = 'center', content = box, size_hint=(None, None),
                size=(600, 500))

        btn1.bind(on_release = popup2.dismiss)

        popup2.open()


        c.close()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: The code is large and doesn't represent your question. Please, narow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i have removed the code that was not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the date picker a member of the `LogSheet` class by using `self`. Then you can access it from other methods (functions) of the same class using `self.dp1`:

```
def choose_date_water(self):
    box = FloatLayout()
    box.add_widget(Label(text = "Select Date To View", font_size = (30), pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.9 }))

    self.dp1 = box.add_widget(DatePicker(pHint_x = (0.35), pHint_y = (0.55), size_hint = (None, None), size = (190, 50), font_size = (33), pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.6 }))
    # etc...
```

Now `self.dp1` is a member of the class and is accessible in other methods of that class. You can access it in `view_water_figures()` like this:

```
def view_water_figures(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('logsheet.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT today_total_dw_vol, today_total_fw_vol, total_evap_out FROM waterfigures WHERE date = ?", (self.dp1.text,))
    wf = c.fetchall()
    # etc...
```

Firstly use the cursor to run the query, not the connection. Secondly use `self.dp1` to access the date picker. The date picker probably provides a `text` attribute that contains the date value selected by the user (not sure which widget you're using).

Your use of the parameterised query is correct, however, it is not necessary to call `conn.commit()` when performing read operations on the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help with that one, much appreciated.  I am now having an error with the DatePicker widget (Which is a text_input widget) where i am getting an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.  It is a different problem to my original so i will re-post as another question.

Comment: @Aiden: you just need to figure out which attribute of the date picker contains the selected date. Since it is based on a text widget I guessed that it might be `.text`, but perhaps not.